# multiArr.shift() giving Error TypeError: Cannot find function shift in object SN

Tags: json, spreadsheet

I am a newbee in Java app development and I am trying to export JSON from google spreadsheet.

I was watching a tutorial and come across this Code

```js
function doGet(){
  var result ={};
  
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  .getDataRange()
  .getValue();
  
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  .getDataRange()
  .getValue();
  
  result.sheet1 = makeObject(sheet1);
  result.sheet2 = makeObject(sheet2);
  
  Logger.log(result.sheet1);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  
}
function makeObject(multiArr){
  var obj = {};
  
  var headers = multiArr.shift();
  
  for(var i= 0; 1<headers.length; i++){
    obj[headers[i]]= multiArr.map(function(app){
      return app[i];
    });
      }
  
  return obj;
}
```

In tutorial it is working fine but for me it is giving an error
TypeError: Cannot find function shift in object SN. (line 23, file "Code")

I am unable to debug it.
Please help

Comment: For some reason instead of giving array (var sheet1, var sheet2) are giving single value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  .getDataRange()
  .getValue();
```

I was using `.getValue()` this was giving only one value, use `.getValues()` to get entire array.

Now arrray multiArr will have objects that can shift. This solves my problem.